# employee count by year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to count number of employees by year even if no employee joined in that year:
e.g.

```
emp_id start_dt term dt 
----------
1      1/1/2010  
----------
2      1/1/2011 12/31/2011
----------
3      1/1/2013
----------
4      1/1/2015 12/31/2016
----------
5      1/1/2016 
----------
```

i need to print no of employees for each year starting the firs occurrence to sysdate, i.e.

```
2010 1
----------
2011 2
----------
2012 1
----------
2013 2
----------
2014 2
----------
2015 3
----------
2016 4
----------
2017 3
----------
2018 3
----------
2019 3
```

Comment: and please share with us what have tried so far.

Comment: in my original requirement, i needed the counts by dept Id, so i self joined the table on dept id and added the date conditions in join, i am able get the correct counts but for only the rows which are on the table, for other years i am missing the rows

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to start with a table that has all the years of concern.  Then you can count the number of active employees in that year.

For instance,

```
select y.year,
       (select count(*)
        from t
        where year(t.startdt) <= y.year and
              (year(t.termdt) >= y.year or t.termdt is null)
from (select 2011 as year union all
      select 2012 as year union all
      . . .  -- continue for the years of interest
     ) y;
```

This uses the `year()` function, which is not standard but available in many databases.  The official function is `extract(year from startdt)`.

In Oracle, you can express this as:

```
select y.year,
       (select count(*)
        from t
        where extract(year from t.startdt) <= y.year and
              (extract(year from t.termdt) >= y.year or t.termdt is null)
from (select 2011 as year from dual union all
      select 2012 as year from dual union all
      . . .  -- continue for the years of interest
     ) y;
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
select  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIREDATE),count(*) from scott.emp group by EXTRACT(YEAR FROM 
HIREDATE);
```

for your case query wil be:

```
select  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM START_DT ),count(*) from tablename group by EXTRACT(YEAR FROM 
START_DT );
```